# inject html without using jscript

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
<ul id="myList">
   <li class="li1">Example 1</li>
   <li class="li2">Example 2</li>
   <li class="li3">Example 3</li>
   <li class="li4">Example 4</li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way i can transform the list to:

```
<ul class="myList">
   <li class="li1"><div class="container">Example 1</div></li>
   <li class="li2"><div class="container">Example 2</div></li>
   <li class="li3"><div class="container">Example 3</div></li>
   <li class="li4"><div class="container">xample 4</div></li>
</ul>
```

<strike>using css only</strike>.
without using javascript

Comment: thought so... currently i am using javascript to alter the html, however, i want it to work even if js is disabled on the browser.

Does anyone know of an alternative way without using javascript then?

Comment: There's no way to add elements without JavaScript (can you not do this on the server?)  If you're doing this for display purposes, take a look at the styling below...if that's not what you're after please comment what it doesn't do compare to what you're after.

Comment: my problem is, i have a list on a site, the contents of which is loaded dynamically(componenents developed by other users), i don't want them to bother with the container css, as that is applied by the admin (like dotnetnuke handles it). hence, i must be able to wrap the contents of the li with a container. but like i said, javascript should not be used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS cannot add elements, that really isn't its purpose.

That being said, you can achieve a similar *effect* by making the items `display: block`, like this:

```
#myList > li { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

No. CSS is designed to instruct the browser on how elements look and are positioned. It isn't capable of editing the live HTML.